# Simulate click on iframe element

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dom-events

I am trying to simulate click on iframe element. I am sure that the very simple code is working, click actually happens but the behavior is not the same as real mouse click.

Code:

```
<iframe id="iframe2" src="...">
</iframe>

<script>
setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("iframe2").click();
}, 5000);
</script>
```

If I really click on the iframe a new browser tab opens.
If I simulate the click using Javascript or jQuery there is click but nothing happens (no new tab opening).

I need to have the same result.

Comment: Please provide a real example with a working iframe for the test

Comment: Most probably not possible ina way you want it to work. I bet the browser prevents this behavior for security reasons.

Comment: When you "click on the iframe," are you perhaps clicking on specific content loaded within the iframe (e.g. a link or button inside the iframe)? Or do you really have a click event listener attached to the iframe itself, in the parent/root document?

Comment: When you "click on the iframe," are you perhaps clicking on specific content loaded within the iframe (e.g. a link or button inside the iframe)?

YES! the iframe contains like a javascript banner.